# Open With option from Explorer in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

If I right-click a .bat file, I get the context options "Open" and "Edit", but not "Open with...". Is it possible to tinker with the "Open with..." list? More specifically, how do I tinker with the "Edit" application which is currently Notepad (for .bat files). I seem to remember this being fairly simple in Windows XP.